# Clear select2 div when the ko observable is cleared

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am having the following ko `select2` binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).select2(valueAccessor());

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
    }
};
```

Following is my `input` with select2 binding:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $root.Name, attr: { 'placeholder': 'Full Name' }, select2: { minimumInputLength: 1, query: $root.list_item, allowClear: true, multiple: true}">
```

Everything is working perfectly fine. The problem I am facing is when I am clearing the `Name` observable through a `Clear` button, the values selected by the `select2` div are not getting cleared. What change I have to do in the `select2` ko binding to reflect the changes in the UI when the observable is cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Name` is cleared, knockout clears also the `value` attribute of the input element.

`select2` plugin does not track this and does not update its inner value. One solution is, in the custom binding handler, to subscribe to the value binding and clear `select2` when the value is empty:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).select2(valueAccessor());
        // if a value binding exists, subscribe to it 
        // to clear the select2 plugin when the value is empty
        var valueBindingAccessor = allBindings.get('value');
        if(valueBindingAccessor) {
            valueBindingAccessor.subscribe(function(val) {
                if(val == '') {
                    $(element).select2("val", "");
                }
            });
        }
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
    }
};
```